# Regular expression with backslash in swift

Tags: swift, regex, uitextview

i am having problems using replacingOccurrences to replace a word after some specific keywords inside a textview in swift 5 and Xcode 12.

For example:
My textview will have the following string "NAME\JOHN PHONE\555444333"

"NAME" and "PHONE" will be unique so anytime i change the proper field i want to change the name or phone inside this textview.

let's for example change JOHN for CLOE with the code

```
txtOther.text = txtOther.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "NAME(.*?)\\s", with: "NAME\\\(new_value) ", options: .regularExpression)
print (string)
```

output: "NAMECLOE " instead of "NAME\CLOE "

I can't get the backslash to get print according to the regular expression.

Or maybe change the regex expression just to change JOHN for CLOE after "NAME"

Thanks!!!

Ariel

Comment: `with: "NAME\\\\\(newValue)"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using a *raw* string for your regular expresion, that is a string surrounded with `#`

```
let pattern = #"(NAME\\)(.*)\s"#
```

Note that name and the \ is in a separate group that can be referenced when replacing

```
let output = string.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "$1\(new_value) ", options: .regularExpression)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```swift
"NAME\\JOHN PHONE\\555444333".replacingOccurrences(
    of: #"NAME\\(\S+)"#, 
    with: "NAME\\\\\(new_value)",
    options: .regularExpression
)
```

Double backslashes in the replacement, backslash is a special metacharacter inside a replacement.

`\S+` matches one or more characters different from whitespace, this is shorter and more efficient than `.*?\s`, and you do not have to worry about how to put back the whitespace.